# How to use context provider with react router components?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx, use-context

I have browsed almost every resource on the internet and have not found a solution so please don't recommend me someone else's question that is identical because I have most likely already tried it.

[image: Router Component]

Here is my container that has all of the routes. These reside in the App component which is basically the uppermost component.

[image: Context Provider]

Here is my provider. Basically, I have a title and when you click on the different links that take you to different views (i.e., Home, Client, Company) I do something like...

```
const { setHeader } = useContext(HeaderContext);

useEffect(() => {
    setHeader("Company Dashboard");
    document.title = "Company Dashboard"
})
```

As you can see the "setHeader("Company Dashboard")" should set the header. The header is actually a separate component that rerenders if the HeaderContext updates.

The Provider works btw. This is because the Header component has uses this context to set the  element. So if I change the empty string to "oeijsofiej" it will display "oeijsofiej" as the title BUT it does NOT change when you click on different tabs.

I have tried to surround all of the  components in a  but unfortunately, that does absolutely nothing. No errors thrown and the setContext doesn't do anything. I have tried other ways of formatting the  element like

```
<Route path="/" exact render={() => <HeaderContextProvider><Home></HeaderCOntextProvider>}/>
```

Unfortunately, this also does nothing. I've tried other methods and get weird errors. Not sure what I'm doing wrong I've exhausted all of my resources. Please help.

Comment: Please provide a codesandbox of your code.

Comment: I have set up as you have mentioned and got it working without any issues. You must have an issue somewhere you have not shared the code. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-b6r9rv

set up your code somewhere so anyone can easily help.

Comment: The solution here was to just go with React-Redux..... saves so much of a headache